# set relative query to datasource

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-query, querybuilder

Each Article uses datasource underneath.

[image]

I'm using query to find CTA button of current item but it returns nothing.

> query:.//Article Datasource/Article Top Content

.

[image]

Comment: I think just using `./Article Datasource/Article Top Content/` will work.

Comment: Also see this. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13718/relative-datasource-for-template-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the spaces. `./#Article Datasource#/#Article Top Content#`. Sitecore Query queries must be escaped when containing spaces.

See also:

- [Escaping reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687405/escaping-reserved-words)
- [Sitecore Query Cheat Sheet](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet)
- [Sitecore Query fails - “::” expected at position 92](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/sitecore-query-fails-expected-at-position-92)

Comment: Good call on the `#` for the spaces.